# Can't push data from firebase to array by using foreach in Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to fetch data from firebase firestore, which I get what I wanted by `console.log()`. But when I tried to store what I get to array using `push()`. It gives me empty value in return. Here is my code:

```
app.post('/getMemberInfo', async (req, res) => {
  var memberKeyList = req.body.member
  var memRef = await db.collection("user")
  let newArray = []
  memberKeyList.forEach((row) => {
    memRef.doc(row.MemberID).get().then((doc)=>{

        newArray.push(doc.data())
        console.log(doc.data())

      

    })
    
  })
  res.send(newArray)
})
```

Here on `console.log` I got all data, but in `newArray` it returns empty array. What did I do wrong here? Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each `get()` call is an asynchronous operation, and your `res.send(newArray)` runs before any of these calls complete (which you can see by adding some more logging and checking the order of the output).

The solution is to use `Promise.all` to wait for all the asynchronous operations to complete before sending the result back to the client:

```
app.post('/getMemberInfo', async (req, res) => {
  var memberKeyList = req.body.member
  var memRef = await db.collection("user")
  let newArray = []
  const docs = Promise.all(memberKeyList.map((row) => memRef.doc(row.MemberID).get()));
  const newArray = docs.map((doc)=> doc.data());
  res.send(newArray)
})
```

Comment: I got empty on docs, it doesn't give any result.